# Errors while running MITMf

Tags: logging, man-in-the-middle

I'm having a problem when I run the `python mimtf.py -v` command, it displays the following message:

```
    Traceback most recent call last
    File /home/jorel/MITMf/mitmf.py, line 28, in module
        from core.proxyplugins import ProxyPlugins
    File /home/jorel/MITMf/core/proxyplugins.py, line 26, in module
        log = logger().setup_logger("ProxyPlugins", formatter)
    File /home/jorel/MITMf/core/logger.py, line 44, in setup_logger
        logger.setLevel(self.log_level)
    File /usr/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py, line 1464, in setLevel
        self.level = _checkLevel(level)
    File /usr/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py, line 210, in _checkLevel
        raise TypeError("Level not an integer or a valid string: %r")
    TypeError: Level not an integer or a valid string: None
```

I've done several pip installation and update commands, but nothing helps.